# Create a Playing Board

Tags: c, c99

Board dimensions are taken in and if the user enters:

```
row = 4
columns = 3
```

I have written the code but I can only get the board to display:

```
...
...
...
...
```

```c
Board* createBoard(int rows, int cols) {
    Board *board = malloc(sizeof(Board));

    board->contents = malloc(sizeof(char*) * rows);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < rows ; ++i) {
        board->contents[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (cols+2));
        memset(board->contents[i], '.', cols);
        board->contents[i][cols] = '\n';
        board->contents[i][cols+1] = '\0';
    }
    board->rows = rows;
    board->cols = cols;
    return board;
}

void show_Board(Board *board) {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < board->rows; ++i) {
        fprintf(stdout,"%s",board->contents[i]);
    }
}

int main () {
    Board *board = malloc(sizeof(Board));
    board = createBoard(4,3);
    show_Board(board);
}
```

The format of the playing board after input from user.

```
......
......
......
......
```

So instead of just showing one character per column, in this case dot(.), I need to show two characters per column like above.

Comment: Do your fprint twice.  Or `fprintf(stdout,"%s%s",board->contents[i], board->contents[i]);`

Comment: Why are you allocating a `board pointer` twice (once in `int main`, the other in `createBoard`)?

Comment: You don't have to.  Just allocate it once, either in `main` or in `createBoard`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey instead of using fprint twice is there a way I can store it in the memory?

Comment: Sure, but why would you do that?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it's because I would like to use that board and do more operations on it.